# Probability Density Function Notation

Tags: probability, density-function

So Im new to pdf's and am doing some preliminary research on the topic. I came across notation that I didn't understand. The problem I found said this:

> A random variable I has the following PDF:
>
> $P_i(i) = \frac{4i}{a^2} U(i)$
>
> where the variable i is simple the value of the random variable I.
>    Determine the PDF of the new random variable:
>
> $X = \frac{1}{I}$
>
> using the following approaches: 
>   a) the direct technique, i.e.,
>   calculating the Jacobian of the inverse transformation, etc., and b)
>   by first determining the CDF of the new RV, X, and then
>   differentiating.

In the notation above, what does the U(i) mean. Is it specifying a uniform distribution?

Comment: Can you supply the reference to that problem?

Comment: @JimB I've updated the question to show the full question that was asked. It's just a random problem from a probability textbook

Comment: Not all spaces have uniform distributions. In particular, any unbounded subset of $\Bbb R$ does not. So unless $I$ is restricted to some bounded range, $U(i)$ cannot be a uniform distribution. You need to search the context of this problem in the textbook to figure out what $U(i)$ is supposed to be.